# Issues with Short Term visa for Iceland

Tags: visas, schengen, iceland, denmark, proof-of-employment

**My Background**

I am from India living in Canada with a work permit. I want to visit Iceland and for this I need to apply for Short stay visa.

**Visa Requirement**

The embassy of Denmark which handles the visa for Iceland is asking for the employment letter having this line :

Letter from your employer indicating when you began working and if you are able to return to your job.

http://canada.um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/visas/step-2-collecting-supporting-documentation//~/media/Canada/Documents/Consular/Visa/Visa%20-%20Visitor%20Checklist.pdf

**Problem**

My company is not agreeing to give me this letter which says "if you are able to return to your job."

I am unable to figure out the solution, can some one please suggest me (such as other proof that I can submit to the embassy, or the change in wording of the letter) that can help me in securing the visa.

Comment: Can you ask your employer to say that you are authorized to take temporary vacation leave during the trip?  Perhaps "temporary," which implies a return to work, would be sufficient.  In any event, I would ask my employer what statements they *are* willing to make.

Comment: Here in Qatar few embassies ask for guarantee of return on their websites for visa info, which no company can ever give, so they give/write that employee is supposed to join work on xxyyzz date, and most of the time embassies accept that..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I am trying to convince my employer. Lets see what happens next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your employer is likely overinterpreting what is asked of them.  The embassy is not looking for a legally binding guarantee, just for something that tells them that **you reasonably believe you will still have a job when you return**.

The embassy always starts with a suspicion that your real intention is to immigrate illegally to the Schengen area and seek work there. Your task as an applicant is to prove that it is not so, by showing that *it is in your own best interests to return to Canada after your visit*.  Having a good job to return to goes a long way for this, but only if you're not going to get fired from it if you abscond to Iceland and don't come in for weeks. So they want to know you have actually agreed with your employer to take vacation in such-and-such period, and that's what the "return to your job" language is for.

It ought to satisfy the embassy if your employer writes a letter reading something like

> To whom it may concern:
>   John Doe has been employed with Yoyodyne Canada Ltd since November 2005 as a Senior Underwater Basket Weaver.  We have mutually agreed that he will take vacation between December 3 and December 11, 2016.

(or hopefully at a time that is more opportune for experiencing Iceland).

Comment: *hopefully at a time that is more opportune for experiencing Iceland* and hopefully from a more lucrative job than Underwater Basket-Weaving, which is notoriously badly-paid, especially by those cheapskates at Yoyodyne Canada.  Iceland's an expensive place.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there is a more opportune time for visiting Iceland than early December where it’s likely to be nice, cold and dark.

Comment: Thanks a lot all for your advice. I am trying to convince my employer. Lets see what happens next

Comment: So I am putting this information here it might be useful for others: i took the printout of my vacation and got it signed. Also the VFS team said that we know that companies dont give the "asked" in written so even without the vacation letter it is fine.